# Do Class Skill Bonuses Count as Ranks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, skills, dnd-3e, conversion

In Pathfinder do class skill bonuses count as ranks, especially for the purpose of prestige classing, or are they a generic bonus?

If they are a bonus, how should I adjust the required ranks for prestige classes and feats when converting from D&D3?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No, they do not.**

[Skill ranks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Acquiring-Skills) refer only to the number of well, *ranks* that you've put into the skill.

I can't find an exact reference to back that up, but they make a big deal when referring to ranks vs bonuses:

> Each level, your character gains a
>   number of skill ranks dependent upon
>   your class plus your Intelligence
>   modifier. Investing a rank in a skill
>   represents a measure of training in
>   that skill. You can never have more ranks in a skill than your total number of Hit Dice.

And

> Each skill rank grants a +1 bonus on
>   checks made using that skill.

Since you can only have a number of Ranks in a given skill equal to your level, that means that a minimum number of ranks is effectively a level requirement.

So, when for example you have an [Assassin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/assassin) who has a requirement of minimum 5 ranks in Stealth, you must be at least 6th level before even being able to become an assassin.

Edit:

You're doing conversions! This free PDF will cover most of what you need to do: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/v5748btpy89m6 (You do need a Paizo account to download it, but that too is free).

From the Prestige Classes section in the conversion guide:

> Make sure to check the prestige class
>   requirements (and the rest of the
>   class) for any skills that have been
>   altered or removed from the game and
>   adjust them accordingly. In addition,
>   the skill rank requirements should be
>   equal to the 3.5 requirements – 3
>   (minimum 1 rank). Note that some of
>   the core prestige classes do not
>   follow this formula exactly and you
>   should consider these requirements
>   carefully.

Comment: Well then, how do I need to adjust?  Subtract 3?

Comment: @C. Ross You're not keeping track of ranks separately? On most of the sheets I've seen there's a column for "rank" and then all the other columns. For Example, I use this sheet and I like it: http://www.pathfinderdb.com/character-sheets/static-character-sheets/84-neceros-pfrpg-character-sheet. It has a column for "Class skill bonus" as well, so you can keep track of those things.

Comment: But yes, if you're not tracking rank vs bonus subtracting 3 will work.

Comment: @Cthos Adjust feats and class requirements, from D&D 3.5.

Comment: OOOH! You're doing conversions! Well why didn't you say so? :) (You did but I missed it). Editing my answer.

Comment: Interesting.  I always thought when a prestige class required a skill level, it said something like +4 to Stealth.  I've always assumed that would include skill ranks, the +1 from being a class skill, relevant feats, and whatever ability modifier is appropriate to the skill.

Comment: @Pulsehead Well, in Pathfinder, a class skill gives you a +3 if you have at least 1 rank in it. Prestige classes specifically ask for "Ranks" whereas that +3 for class skill is a "bonus". This is a departure from how 3.5 did skills, they streamlined it a bit and altered what a class skill actually meant.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't.

But if you're making a conversion, using the standard method of requiring 3 less ranks than it would on 3.x could result in awkward conversions.

Several 3.x prestige classes work on the assumption that you're purchasing some cross-class skills. That's mostly the case of "8 ranks of this plus 4 ranks of this, this and that".

Personally, I'd rule that you need a score of (3.x ranks needed) between ranks and the +3 bonus for putting ranks in a class skill.

Answer (score 0):

No. Ranks are raw skill. All other bonuses are just that, bonuses, and added after the fact. Anything that specifies skill rank as a requirement means the raw skill rate, not the adjusted one.