# Do racial bonuses to skills count toward ranks for synergy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, races

Page 61 of The Players Handbook says (emphasis mine):

> **Skill Ranks**: A character’s number of ***ranks*** in a skill is
>   based on ***how many skill points*** a character has invested in a
>   skill. Many skills can be used even if the character has no
>   ranks in them; doing this is called making an untrained skill
>   check.

and

> **Miscellaneous Modifiers**: Miscellaneous modifiers
>   include ***racial bonuses***, armor check penalties, and bonuses
>   provided by feats, among others.

And Page 66 says Skill Synergy:

> It’s possible for a character to have two skills that work well
>   together, such as someone with both Jump and Tumble. In general,
>   having 5 or more ***ranks*** in one skill gives the character a +2 bonus on
>   skill checks with each of its synergistic skills,

So I read this to mean Racial Bonuses to Skills do not count toward the required 5 ranks for Synergy. This seems counter-intuitive to me, in respect that if you're good at Use Rope, I'd expect it counts towards Escape Artist with rope because I'm just so damned good at using ropes.

Is this correct from a Rules as Written point of view?
Does this make sense outside of a strict Rules as Written view?

Comment: [Related question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8112/do-class-skill-bonuses-count-as-ranks?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The rules say 5 or more skill *ranks* are required for a bonus from [synergy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#skillSynergy)...

That is, [Skill Synergy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#skillSynergy) says

> It’s possible for a character to have two skills that work well together. In general, having 5 or more ranks in one skill gives the character a +2 bonus on skill checks with each of its synergistic skills, as noted in the skill description. In some cases, this bonus applies only to specific uses of the skill in question, and not to all checks. Some skills provide benefits on other checks made by a character, such as those checks required to use certain class features.

That means, for example, a [minotaur](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/minotaur.htm) with 1 rank in the skill [Search](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/search.htm) because of its +4 racial bonus on Search skill checks does *not* get a +2 bonus due to synergy to Survival skill checks made to find or to follow tracks, and a [rakshasa](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/rakshasa.htm) with 1 ranks in the skill [Bluff](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/bluff.htm) because of it's +4 racial bonus on Bluff skill checks does *not* get a +2 bonus due to synergy on Diplomacy, Intimidate, and Sleight of Hand skill checks as well as Disguise skill checks when observed and acting in character.

### ...But make a house rule if you don't like it

If this rule doesn't make sense to you, and you're the DM, change it. If this rules doesn't make sense to you, and you're a player, convince the DM to change it. Seriously, though, in the end, getting a +2 bonus from synergy early likely won't break the game, and neither will getting a +2 bonus from synergy you wouldn't normally receive. It's a +2 bonus; it's rare that anyone will *remember* the house rule after level 5.

Comment: Note that letting people use bonuses instead of ranks to qualify for things is dangerous - synergy is okay, but things like feats and prestige classes use skill rank requirements as a level barrier. This houserule may be a slippery slope, so you should read the situation carefully before implementing it.

Comment: @SPavel Fortunately, that's beyond the scope of the question, which concerns itself solely with synergy. I totally agree that using skill *bonuses* instead of skill *ranks* to meet prerequisites and requirements is nuts.